# How to generate the following numbers

Tags: scripting

I need to generate a sequence like this one:

1, 6, 11, 2, 7, 12, 3, 8, 13, 4, 9, 14

What's going to be the code like?

Comment: `echo 1, 6, 11, 2, 7, 12, 3, 8, 13, 4, 9, 14`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a shell script

```
 for ((i=1; i<5 ; i++))
 do
     printf '%d, %d, %d, ' $i $((i+5)) $((i+10))
 done
 echo
```

It will have an extra comma after the 14, this can be fixed if it matters.

Comment: I corrected a small typo. Hope that's okay...

Comment: thanks.. looks good!

Comment: @Freddy Correcting typos is always OK with me.